# Background image that only fits one full screen

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Anyone has any idea how this page does it. 
Looking towards the same idea.

http://whois.domaintools.com/

If you notice the picture of the desert will always cover my entire browser screen.
However, this is not like a regular full screen background as the moment I scroll down the background image ends.

Does anyone have any ideas on how they might have achieved this?
Thanks:))

Comment: Can you please post some code that you have tried so we can help determine your problem. Html and CSS thanks

Comment: Quite a cool canvas too :D

Comment: you can use scripting to find window height and set image height as per that value.

Comment: That desert bg image calling from css, not in canvas .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic examples.

**Pure CSS**

```css
*,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
.banner {
  background: url('http://whois.domaintools.com/images/backgrounds/dark-desert-hills.jpg') no-repeat top center scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```

demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/3uLrqfz8/1/

**Jquery**

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  //banner height
  $('.banner').height($(window).height());
}).resize();
```

```css
*,html{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.banner {
  background: url('http://whois.domaintools.com/images/backgrounds/dark-desert-hills.jpg') no-repeat top center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner"></div>
```

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/3uLrqfz8/

Answer (score 0):

It has CSS styling:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
```

for the canvas with the id of "spiders" LOL
(using inspect element)

Answer (score 0):

I use `jQuery` to ensure the container is always the height of the viewport. This translates well responsively too;

```
    vpw = $(window).width();
    vph = $(window).height();
    $(".your-container").css({"height": vph + "px"});
```

Example of a a site I used it on here: http://startnetwork.org/

Tip:

Add it to a window resize function to handle user switching orientation on devices eg. iPad

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function resize () {
        vpw = $(window).width();
        vph = $(window).height();
        $(".your-container").css({"height": vph + "px"});
  }

  resize();
});
```

Comment: hello!!! I really like your site. Thinking if I should use your canvas instead as it fits the style I'm going for. Really nice work on the site. May I ask what css did you use or are they all original?

Comment: Thank you it was a team effort and it's only phase 1 at the moment! Here is the canvas example you can use http://codepen.io/Zaku/pen/vFDdw

Comment: wow that's pretty amazing!! may I have permission to use it for my site?

Comment: how do I turn off the stats for canvas? haha THANKS A BUNCH

Comment: Use this CSS .dg.a { display:none:} or you can remove it via the .js. This is not my original work. I changed it for the site I worked on above. See the Codepen T&Cs

Comment: If you found my answer useful please upvote it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The codes for the background originate from [GreenSock](http://greensock.com/)

The codes that actually do the tasks have been extracted to their own custom Javascript file`.`

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zbyraez2/)